# How to make a custom colormap using PyPlot (not matplotlib proper)

Tags: matplotlib, julia, colormap

Working in IJulia. Desperately trying to make a custom colormap.
Tried the line:

```
matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap([(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)],"A")
```

which resulted in the following error

> type PyObject has no field colors while loading In[16], in expression starting on line 1

which apparently means that I cannot use matplotlib directly, but only the functions which are in PyPlot.

I cannot involve matplotlib with an import (as this is invalid in IJulia).
I have noted that others have had help on similar problems, but that doesn't solve mine.

Answer (score 4):

By using the PyCall package which PyPlot is using to wrap matplotlib you can obtain a colormap like this:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.colors as matcolors
cmap = matcolors.ListedColormap([(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)],"A")
```

In order to access fields in a PyObject you need to index the object with a symbol like:

```
cmap[:set_over]((0,0,0))
```

This is equivalent to: `cmap.set_over((0,0,0))` in python. For other good examples of how to plot different kinds of plots using PyPlot, see these examples: https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfect. Jusst wondering how I could have found this solution by using the ressources on the net. Any suggestions. I am not very impressed of the documentation as a help for novices. Also thanks very much for the tidying up on my original question.

Comment: When using a package the best way to obtain knowledge is to look in the readme on GitHub, see  https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/blob/master/README.md.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use PyCall to call Python directly (although this is, of course, an option).  You can also just use the `PyPlot` constructors for `ColorMap` to construct a colormap from (r,g,b) arrays or an array of colors as defined in the Julia `Color` package.  See the [PyPlot ColorMap documentation](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl#color-maps).  For example:

```
using PyPlot, Color
ColorMap("A", [RGB(1,0,0),RGB(0,1,0),RGB(0,0,1)])
```